# How to prevent Rcpp to change some value in R?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have this C++ function:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> list_to_faces(const Rcpp::List L) {
  const size_t nfaces = L.size();
  std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> faces;
  faces.reserve(nfaces);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < nfaces; i++) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector face_rcpp = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(L(i));
    face_rcpp = face_rcpp - 1;
    std::vector<size_t> face(face_rcpp.begin(), face_rcpp.end());
    faces.emplace_back(face);
  }
  return faces;
}
```

As you see, it takes a list as argument. In my code this is a list of integer vectors, and the function converts the list to another object, *after subtracting 1 to each vector of the list*.

This R command:

```r
mesh <- Mesh(vertices, faces, normals = FALSE)
```

calls the above C++ function, where `faces` is the list in question. Originally, this is this list:

```
> faces
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 7 6

[[4]]
[1] 2 3 8 7

[[5]]
[1] 3 4 9 8

[[6]]
[1]  4  5 10  9

[[7]]
[1]  5  1  6 10
```

But after I execute the R command, the list becomes:

```
> faces
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1] 0 1 6 5

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 7 6

[[5]]
[1] 2 3 8 7

[[6]]
[1] 3 4 9 8

[[7]]
[1] 4 0 5 9
```

That is, the action of the C++ function, subtracting 1, is propagated to R. How can I prevent that?

Comment: You may want to take a look at a few of the answers in [Section 5 of the Rcpp FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! I think I will do the subtraction in R, that's the easiest way imho. Since I already use a **lapply** call to the list, adding the subtraction will not be an important time cost.

Comment: Or you could deep copy the object if you need to modify it locally. The `SEXP` nature and its pointer implementation do have this cost for us.